# Impact winters and understanding their “impact”

Tags: post-apocalypse, weather, extinction, meteor

I have visited Impact Earth! and love the amount of information. I understand the information on how much particulate would be ejected into the atmosphere. However, there are no calculations for how long the particulates would stay in the atmosphere and for how long the winter could last. I want to make my world as plausible as possible. Can anyone help?

Important information:
The meteor is composed of an alien metal that has roughly the same density of iron. It is “alive” so to speak and can control its own velocity while in the atmosphere. The impact happens at a 45 degree angle at 7 km/s. The density is ~8000 kg/m<sup>3</sup>. The meteor strikes land in a sparsely populated area.

Comment: For what kind of impact? What is the mass, velocity and composition of the impactor? Where will it hit and at what angle?

Comment: Density of 8000kg/m^3 (iron). Size 1 km. 45 degree angle. Speed of 7 km/s. The impact location is on land.

Comment: *"Speed of 7 km/s:"* Not possible. An object cannot come from interplanetary space with a speed of less than 11 km/s (= second cosmic speed).

Comment: @Unwritten you should put important details in the question, rather than in the comment thread.

Comment: That is true. However, the meteor is made of “living metal” (better name forthcoming) and can slow itself down. While in interplanetary space, it travels at much faster than 11 km/s.

Comment: @Strfish Prime I should have. Thanks. I’m new here and I appreciate the info.

Comment: You forgot a crucial piece of information: the dimension of the impactor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, for a large impact the particulate launched in the high atmosphere stays there for some years and its impact on global climate lasts something more than that. The ashes in the high atmosphere prevent some of the solar light from reaching the surface, with evident consequences on the climate.

You can compare it with the effect of large volcanic eruptions, like the one of [Mount Toba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toba_catastrophe_theory)

> Despite these different estimates, scientists agree that a supervolcanic eruption of the scale at the Lake Toba Caldera must have led to very extensive ash-fall layers and injection of noxious gases into the atmosphere, with worldwide effects on weather and climate.
>
> Geologist Michael R. Rampino and volcanologist Stephen Self argue that the eruption caused a "brief, dramatic cooling or 'volcanic winter'", which resulted in a drop of the global mean surface temperature by 3–5 °C.
>
> According to Alan Robock, who has also published nuclear winter papers, the Toba eruption did not precipitate the last glacial period. However, assuming an emission of six billion tons of sulphur dioxide, his computer simulations concluded that a maximum global cooling of approximately 15 °C occurred for three years after the eruption, and that this cooling would last for decades, devastating life.

If you want a more recent example, there is the [eruption of mount Tambora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1815_eruption_of_Mount_Tambora#Global_effects) in 1815:

> By most calculations, the eruption of Tambora was at least a full order of magnitude (10 times) larger than that of Mount Pinatubo in 1991. (Graft et al. 1993) An estimated 1,220 metres (4,000 ft) of the top of the mountain collapsed to form a caldera, reducing the height of the summit by a third. Around 100 cubic kilometres (24 cu mi) of rock was blasted into the air.(Williams 2012). Toxic gases also were pumped into the atmosphere, including sulfur that caused lung infections. (Cole-Dai et al. 2009) Volcanic ash was over 100 centimetres (39 in) deep within 75 kilometres (47 mi) of the eruption, while areas within a 500 kilometres (310 mi) radius saw a 5 centimetres (2.0 in) ash fall, and ash could be found as far away as 1,300 kilometres
>
> The ash in the atmosphere for several months after the eruption reflected significant amounts of solar radiation, causing unseasonably cool summers that contributed to food shortages. China, Europe, and North America had well-documented below normal temperatures, which devastated their harvests. The monsoon season in China and India was altered, causing flooding in the Yangtze Valley and forcing thousands of Chinese to flee coastal areas. (Granados et al. 2012) The gases also reflected some of the already-decreased incoming solar radiation, causing a 0.4 to 0.7 °C (0.7 to 1.3 °F) decrease in global temperatures throughout the decade. An ice dam formed in Switzerland during the summers of 1816 and 1817, earning 1816 the title "Year without a Summer".(Bodenmann et al. 2011) The winter months of 1816 were not much different from previous years, but the spring and summer maintained the cool-to-freezing temperatures. The winter of 1817, however, was radically different, with temperatures below −30 °F (−34 °C) in central and northern New York, which were cold enough to freeze lakes and rivers that were normally used to transport supplies. Both Europe and North America suffered from freezes lasting well into June, with snow accumulating to 32 centimetres (13 in) in August, which killed recently planted crops and crippled the food industry. The length of the growing seasons in parts of Massachusetts and New Hampshire were less than 80 days in 1816, resulting in harvest failures.(Oppenheimer 2003) Visually unique sunsets were observed in western Europe, and red fog was observed along the eastern coast of the U.S. These unique atmospheric conditions persisted for the better part of 2.5 years.

Though usually a meteor impact differs from a volcanic eruption in that the latter also injects chemicals like sulfur oxides in the atmosphere, it is also true that if the impactor is large enough to expose the mantle that difference goes away